# In a Plugin registered to the "Merge" Message - how do I know what will be provided in the Target etc?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Supposed I register a Plugin Step to "Merge" of "account". Pic below.

How do I know what the Plugin context/target will provide me? Is there any documentation about what the Plugin context will provide for the different Messages you can register to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin message always has a corresponding `OrganizationRequest` and `OrganizationResponse`.

In this case lookup the `MergeRequest` class. It has 4 custom properties:

1. `Target` - an `EntityReference` pointing to the record that is supposed to be the remaining one.
2. `SubordinateId` - a `Guid` referencing the record that is merged into the target.
3. `UpdateContent` - an `Entity` containing the choices the user made regarding the merged fields.
4. `PerformParentingChecks` - a `bool` allowing you to pre-emptively agree to any parenting changes during the merge.

When you prefer to code early bound, you can use the `IPluginExecutionContext` to get the original `MergeRequest` like this:

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var executionContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    var request = new MergeRequest { Parameters = executionContext.InputParameters };
    // Implementation continues here
}
```

Comment: Never realized this about the "Message" your Plugin is registered to, always has a corresponding C# object e.g. `MergeRequest` and that you can transform the InputParameters INTO that... no idea! How did you know from the docs? Extremely helpful lol.

Comment: Just experience. It also works this way with Actions and Custom API messages. One caveat: there are really old messages, like `Create` and `RetrieveMultiple` that cannot be mapped that easy. But, at some point the MS dev team seems to follow this straightforward naming convention

Answer (score 3):

MSFT documentation shows the JSON payload will be:

POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/Merge HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json

{
"Target": {
"name": "Account 1",
"accountid": "bb8055c0-aea6-ea11-a812-000d3a55d474",
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
},
"Subordinate": {
"name": "Account 2",
"accountid": "c38055c0-aea6-ea11-a812-000d3a55d474",
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
},
"UpdateContent": {
"accountnumber": "1234",
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
},
"PerformParentingChecks": false
}

Is that what you are looking for?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/merge-entity-using-web-api